# cannot call value of non-function type '[UIImage]

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to create an array of images and a method which will allow me to generate a random image.

I've read another question on here, but it didn't really solve my problem, could anyone try to explain to me what's going on here, not just give me the answer.

```
import GameplayKit
import UIKit


struct ImgArray {
    let images = [
        UIImage(named: "emoji01.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "emoji02.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "emoji03.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "emoji04.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "emoji05.png")!
    ]

    func getRandomImage() {
            let randomImage = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextIntWithUpperBound(images.count)
        return images(randomImage)
    }

}
```

Comment: There's nothing complicated going on,  You just have the wrong syntax for subscripting.  [ ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're simply trying to generate a random image, here is a **much** simpler solution:

```
import UIKit

let images = [
    UIImage(named: "emoji01.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "emoji02.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "emoji03.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "emoji04.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "emoji05.png")!
]

func getRandomImage() -> UIImage {
    let number = Int(arc4random_uniform(images.count))
    return images[number]
}
```

What this is doing:

This creates a set of images -

```
let images = [...]
```

This creates a function -

```
func getRandomImage() -> UIImage {
```

Note: the `-> UIImage` part means that the function actually returns an image. You can't return something in a `void` function.

This creates a random number -

```
let number = ...
```

This returns the image -

```
return images[number]
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong kind of bracket:

```
return images(randomImage)
```

Replace that line with:

```
return images[randomImage]
```

Comment: Thanks, that and giving it a return type of UIImage did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

yes, the brakets are wrong, change () to [] because of this

with let images = [...] you create an array. One of many example is [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-swift)

To access an array-**element**, u must take the name of the array followed by **[** the the index (=position) in the array and at least **]**